# Onclick event on an imagemap area element

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following problem. I have a big image (banner) and on it I have two flags which are 2 map areas. I want to do the following: when you click on English flag the language changes to English, when you click on Spanish flag, the language changes to Spanish. I don't know if I should do it with an href or onclick function. I add some code.

```
<img src="banner_trading_1440_x_176_esp.jpg"   usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
 <area shape="rect" coords="1318,14,1346,32" alt="Eng"  href="javascript:window.location.href='<?php echo base_url(); ?> LanguageSwitcher/switchLang/spanish';" >
 <area shape="rect" coords="1276,14,1303,32" alt="Esp" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='<?php echo base_url(); ?> LanguageSwitcher/switchLang/spanish';"/>
</map>
```

Before I had both flags as 2 separate images and the code was like this (and it worked perfectly):

```
  <img style="width: 30px; cursor: pointer; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;" src="http://www.hemptrading.com/tienda3/asserts/img/spain.png" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='<?php echo base_url(); ?> LanguageSwitcher/switchLang/spanish';"/>
```

Comment: Not related to `PHP`. And I think you can skip `javascript:` in `onclick` events. What is your question exactly?

Comment: why not just use a href rather than using javascript window.location?  you only use the javascript on the image as it is not a natural link (personally I would have wrapped it in a link rather than use js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have to call a javascript function from area tag and put your php code in that function definition

`<area shape="rect" coords="1318,14,1346,32" alt="Eng"  href="javascript:your_function();" >`

and add this function of php code

`<script>
function your_function() {
window.location.href='<?php echo base_url(); ?> LanguageSwitcher/switchLang/spanish';
}
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are staying on the page and responding to an event, I'd say use `onclick`.

If you are navigating to a new url, I'd say use `href`.

Since you're navigating to a new url, I'd go with something along the lines of `href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>LanguageSwitcher/switchLang/spanish"`.